# [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, odbc

I've got this error when try to connect an SQL Server 12 database based on windows from an ubuntu 21.10 linux installation. I've successfully established the connection using FreeTDS driver, but I'd like to use ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server.

> DIAG [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider:
> Error code 0x2746 DIAG [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL
> Server]Client unable to establish connection

Comment: What are your connection settings?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72356782/edit) your question to include the connection string that you are using. Obscure the specific server address, username and password used but try to preserve the format of the original connection string especially when it comes to things such as use of instance names, specific port numbers and encryption.

Comment: _sql server 12 database_ Please clarify: do you mean SQL Server 2012 here, or version 12 which is actually SQL Server 2014?

Comment: SQL Server 2012